# I want to install a Virtual machine to install redhat linux os on it in my ubuntu 18.04.Can any one recommend a standard tutorial for that?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rhel, virtual-machine

I am currently using the Ubuntu operating system.I want to install Redhat Linux on it without dual booting.I think I have to use virtual machine for that.But I do not know how it do.

Answer (score 0):

This guide to install the VirtualBox hypervisor on Red Hat:
https://developers.redhat.com/rhel8/install-rhel8-vbox

This guide to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox:
https://brb.nci.nih.gov/seqtools/installUbuntu.html